# How to sort an array by value from an object

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

How to sort the array by likes count?
I tried like this but it doesn't work. If necessary, I can also use a list instead of an array.

```
Array.Sort<Item>(items, (x, y) => x.Likes.Count.CompareTo(y.Likes.Count));

public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    public Likes Likes { get; set; }

}
public class Likes
{
    public long Count { get; set; }

    public long UserLikes { get; set; }

    public long CanLike { get; set; }

    public bool CanPublish { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, could you give a set of example data, and how you're calling the code, what the output is, and what you'd expect the output to be?

Comment: What did not work? What was the actual result and your expectation? As @LukeStorry wrote: This should work

Comment: That seems like it should work but i would recomend using the Linq order by function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Alternatively you can use LINQ: `var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Likes.Count).ToList()`. Use `OrderByDescending` if you wanna have those items with the most likes first.

Comment: `(x, y) => (x.Likes?.Count ?? -1).CompareTo(y.Likes?.Count ?? -1)` if there's a possibility that `Likes` can be `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a possibility that `Likes == null` then the construction *will not* work: `Likes.Count` will *throw exception*; if it's your case, try

```
(x, y) => (x.Likes?.Count ?? -1).CompareTo(y.Likes?.Count ?? -1)
```

comparison instead:

```
Array.Sort<Item>(items, (x, y) => (x.Likes?.Count ?? -1).CompareTo(y.Likes?.Count ?? -1));
```

here we assume that `Likes == null` means `Likes.Count == -1` so these `Likes == null` cases will be on the *top*